# Jenkins periodic build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a possible to prevent the full jenkins job from running, that is periodically scheduled; if there is no SCM changes since the last build.

For example,

There is a daily night build, to create a build. The completion of this job triggers(upstream project) the automation testing job for that build.

I would like to be able to have two things

1. Stop the 1st build job, if there is no SCM change since the last job
2. 2nd upstream automation test job runs only if it has not run for 1 week. (after it has been triggered by the 1st Job)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The first part is simple, instead of "Build periodically" set to "Poll SCM" with the same schedule. It's exactly what it does: periodically checking for changes and only running the job if there were some.

The second part (triggering another job with a time constraint) is more complicated. One option is "Throttle builds" (to 1 per week) in addition to your usual build triggering scheme. Another one is "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" option and checking whether required conditions are met in some sort of script or service.

Comment: Works for the first part, checking the second, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first

Did you try the poll the SCM every night? If no changes, the Jenkins job wont start.

```
0 23 * * *
```

Will run every night at 11 p.m

for the second
use the following plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin

Comment: Okies, let me give it a try.

Comment: If there is no change since previous run, It will start bot not do anything. Only 1-2 sec

Comment: Works for the first part. Thanks :)